# CSS (or jQuery): How to set horizontal scrollbar in the middle position?

Tags: jquery, css, scrollbar, horizontal-scrolling

I work on a website whose main content block is too wide to fit fully inside the smaller resolution screens.

The content is centered in the middle of the screen.

I need a horizontal scrollbar to appear when the content doesn't fit inside the screen.

I force the horizontal scrollbar to appear with a div:

```
<div id="stretcher" style="width:1200px; min-width:1200px; height:1px; position:absolute; margin:0 auto"></div>
```

**The problem:** if I initially open the website in a large resolution screen (or wider window), and then make the browser window narrower, the scrollbar appears just where it's supposed to. However - if I continue making the window narrower, the scrollbar handle stays at the left side, and scrolling further to the left becomes impossible. Also, If the browser window is initially smaller than the content, the scrollbar appears all the way to the left, and I can't scroll more to the left to reveal the left side of the content that is hidden.

**The question: how can I force the scroller to the middle, so that I can scroll left to reveal the hidden part of the content?**

I would be grateful for your advice!

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot? I can't see what you mean.

Comment: Are you able to access the website, Jordan?

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean now. The left-hand side of the screen is getting pushed off the screen to the left by the content on the right.

Comment: Yes. And the scrollbar stays on the left and  has no place to scroll further left to reveal the hidden content.

Comment: Am I correct that the main content area is supposed to be horizontally centered, and the menu is supposed to hang off the left edge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSFiddle of my demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Y9DCs/

From what I can see, right now you have a 2 column layout:

On the left is your "access" panel that contains your menu. On the right is your main content area.

I think you may be better served to have a main container with 3 sections:

```
|----------------wrapper---------------------|
|         |                      |           |
|         |                      |           |
|         |                      |           |
|         |                      |           |
|         |                      |           |
|         |                      |           |
|  Menu   |       Content        |   Dummy   |
|         |                      |           |
|         |                      |           |
|         |                      |           |
|         |                      |           |
|         |                      |           |
|         |                      |           |
|--------------------------------------------|
```

You can then size the width of wrapper as Content + (2 * Menu), and give it margin: 0 auto;

Menu and Dummy would be the same width, except dummy would just be a div with no content.

This will effectively size the whole area as centered on the screen with the menu appearing to hang off the left side of Content.

Comment: This is an interesting idea. Thank you, Jordan! Let me try it. Actually in my layout, Menu is not inside the wrapper. Also, the width of the stretcher div includes the additional width of the "dummy", and the stretcher is set to center with margin:0 auto. Do you think if I create the additional dummy div at the right side, that would improve the situation?

Comment: Tried it. No luck. Would appreciate more ideas from you.

Comment: Yeah, I see that your menu is not in the wrapper, but it should be. I think you can also do away with the idea of a stretcher div. Let me work up a jsFiddle and we can see if it works for you.

Comment: @Dimitri I added a jsFiddle that you can play around with. When I stretch and collapse the screen, it aligns it to the left so the scrollbar allows you to scroll it around correctly. I'm guessing you will need to remove any extraneous elements like your stretcher, etc, and all the positioning/left/top, etc that is currently applied to your layout.

Comment: This looks great, Jordan. I actually tried that, and for some reason things that worked for you didn't work for me. Let me try one more time, following your jsFiddle code more closely.

Comment: It's likely an existing element that you have on your page that will need to be removed. Also, you will have to place these as floats instead of positioned elements.

Comment: Tried it again. Nope, doesn't work in my case. Your solution is correct, of course, but it would require me to dismantle the site, with hundreds of lines of js and php code. I'm afraid it would take a few weeks, and I probably would fail to reassemble it. What would be a duct tape solution, Jordan?

Comment: @Dimitri I'm not sure I have a better solution for you. I think your current template is architected in a way that this bug is going to appear no matter what. The problem is in the left: 50% commands and the stretcher sizes, but those are key to your layout, it seems.

Comment: Thank you Jordan. Let me try to figure this out.

Comment: I managed to figure this out. I wrote a separate answer to my own question, outlining my duct tape solution. However, I'm marking your answer as accepted because your answer helped me to find that solution.

Answer (score 1):

After a day of trial and error I found my own solution, to a great degree inspired by the recommendation made by [Jordan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/311339/jordan) in his answer to my question. Even though my solution is different from that offered by Jordan, but I owe it to him, because he got me thinking in the right direction.

In general, I try to be careful about people's suggestions of drastically rearranging the CSS. In this particular case, it was out of question because the layout of my site is more complex than Jordan's jsFiddle example, and the kinds of jQuery animated effects are only possible with the kind of positioning I was using.

My "duct tape" solution involved wrapping every element of the main block in its own separate wrapper centered with margin:0 auto. This way I didn't need to place the #access div inside the #wrapper div (that was the biggest challenge because it ruined the animations.)

My solution also doesn't involve creating the three-column layout (proposed by Jordan) or a "dummy" div. It proved unnecessary because I am only interested in revealing the left side of the website (the menu).

Still, I want to emphasize once again that I wouldn't be able to solve this without communicating with Jordan about it. That's why I marked Jordan's answer as 'accepted'.

Thank you very much, Jordan!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to wrap all your content in a div called main_wrapper or something and then give it padding-left: 20px or whatever meets your fancy

Comment: Thank you, Luke. I tried that. Unfortunately, it has no effect on the position of the horizontal scrollbar.

Comment: But doesn't that let you see everything starting on the left side, with the scroll bar on the left. This you can see everything except the entire right side, but you'll be able to scroll to it. Maybe I'm wrong though

Comment: The problem is, if the browser window is narrow enough, the scrollbar starts on the left, but part of the site is even further to the left, and there's no place to scroll. Which is exactly the issue I'm battling with. Would appreciate more ideas form you.